# Error:insert hierarchy values using storedprocedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, hierarchyid

I'm getting this error when trying to run a query that inserts results into a table in sql.
im passing the table name as parameter,how to give the hierarchy value to the insert statement.

here is my code:

```
declare @pathhere hierarchyid

select @pathhere=Path from SectionDetails where Sectionid=@sectionid and SectionName=@sectionname and Batchid=@batchid  and Deptid=@deptid and Schoolid=@schoolid
```

insert stmt:

```
set @sqlstmt = 'insert into '+@batch+'(StudentID, StudentName,SectionID,SectionName,BatchID,BatchName, DeptID,DeptName, SchoolID,Path)
values('''+@sectionid+''','''+@sectionname+''','''+@sectionid+''','''+@sectionname+''','''+@batchid+''','''+@batchname+''','''+ @deptid+''','''+@deptname+''', '''+@schoolid+''','+ CAST(@pathhere as hierarchyid)+')'
exec(@sqlstmt)
```

im getting error in this line:

```
'+ CAST(@pathhere as hierarchyid)+'
```

as `Invalid operator for data type. Operator equals add, type equals hierarchyid.`

can anyone pls help me out how to pass the hierarchy value

Comment: This question is unclear. Could you format you query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to create a string that can be executed as a statement. So you need to get your hierarchyid into nvarchar(max) instead.

try:  `@pathhere.ToString()`

Comment: but if i use this im getting 

Could not find method 'Tostring' for type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlHierarchyId' in assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types'

Comment: So you're replacing the part you say is causing you an error with `'+ @pathhere.ToString() +'` , right?

Comment: What does this give you:
select Path, Path.ToString() from SectionDetails where Sectionid=@sectionid and SectionName=@sectionname and Batchid=@batchid  and Deptid=@deptid and Schoolid=@schoolid

Comment: create procedure Copy_school
(
@tablename varchar(500),
@id varchar(500),
@name varchar(500)
)
as
begin
declare @pathhere hierarchyid
declare @sql varchar(max)
select @pathhere= Path from SchoolDetails where Schoolid=@id


set @sql='insert into '+ @tablename+'(Schoolid,SchoolName,School_Ownerid,School_OwnerName,Path)
values('+@id+','+@name+','+@id+','+@name+','+@pathhere+')'
exec(@sql)
end

i need how to pass the hierarchy value path( i.e) @pathhere to insert stmt when i pass my table name dynamically. i need the format to pass the path parameter.

Comment: Have a look at `select Path, Path.ToString() from SectionDetails`, and see what it shows. You want to create a string that handles stuff. Change `exec(@sql)` to `SELECT @sql` so that you can see what it's trying to run.